# Bray-Curtis Dissimilarity Across Life Stages

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to calculate and visualize Bray-Curtis dissimilarity across a set of sites and between life stages. So essentially, I'm trying to create a matrix that can visualize three things:

1. Dissimilarity between all Adult communities
2. Dissimilarity between Adult and Larval communities at the same site
3. Dissimilarity between all Larval communities

I can run the calculation across all of the communities and just hand-pick the comparisons that I actually need (for instance comparison of Adults at site A and Larvae at Site C, doesn't mean much to me, but Adults at site A compared to Larvae at site A is informative). This is effectively what I'm doing through Excel at the moment with Adult comparisons below the diagonal, Larval comparisons above diagonal, and then Adult x Larvae from the same site along the diagonal.

For an example dataset:

```
library(vegan)

Site = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "D", "E") 

LifeStage = c(Ad, Ad, Ad, Ad, Ad, L, L, L, L) 

Sp1 = c(56, 42, 67, 23, 44, 21, 15, 20, 12) 

Sp2 = c(15, 10, 17, 1, 5, 2, 3, 1,6)

Sp3 = c(10, 6, 7, 10, 5, 4, 0, 1, 0)

Sp4 = c(9, 6, 4, 8, 13, 5, 2, 1, 0)

df = data.frame(Site, LifeStage, Sp1, Sp2, Sp3, Sp4)

mat <- df[,3:6]
 
dist.mat <- vegdist (mat, dist = "bray") #All comparisons, but many unnecessary
```

As a note: I am aware that not each site has both adult and larvae data

The best solution I've found was from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200770/bray-curtis-pairwise-analysis-in-r/51230143). I could see this option working, just sounds like it still wouldn't help me skip the need for the manual step mentioned above.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lets you compute just the values you want, but it does not assemble them into a matrix because it is not clear how you want to represent the missing larval stage:

```
(Adult <- vegdist(df[which(df$LifeStage=="Ad"), 3:6], dist="bray"))
#           A_Ad      B_Ad      C_Ad      D_Ad
# B_Ad 0.1688312                              
# C_Ad 0.1135135 0.2201258                    
# D_Ad 0.3636364 0.3207547 0.4890511          
# E_Ad 0.1974522 0.1145038 0.2839506 0.3211009

(Larval <- vegdist(df[which(df$LifeStage=="L"), 3:6], dist="bray"))
#           A_L       B_L       D_L
# B_L 0.2692308                    
# D_L 0.1636364 0.2093023          
# E_L 0.4400000 0.2105263 0.3658537

(unlist(sapply(unique(df$Site), function(x) vegdist(df[which(df$Site==x), 3:6], dist="bray"))))
#         A         B         D         E 
# 0.4754098 0.5238095 0.2923077 0.6000000
```

Comment: In order to keep the final matrix even on each side, I was thinking of just including those columns, but keep them empty. Not perfect, but well that's the 'fun' of field work.